# How to locally run another wordpress site with multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a MAMP server set up, pointing to my main wordpress page that works fine. I have enabled multisite on that page. I'm trying to get someone else's wordpress site running on my local host for development purposes. So I've created a new site from the wordpress admin, linked to the url localhost/newsite.

The wordpress site I'm cloning from simply has a wp-content folder. So my approach has been to create a newsite directory in my main wordpress directory, put all of the config, etc. php files in the newsite directory that are in the main directory, and then simply copy the contents of newsite's wp-content folder to the wp-content folder in the newsite directory I created.

When I visit localhost/newsite, however, I'm simply given a blank page. I'm not at all sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a blank page, it means something broke (yea you already know that). Best place to check is your apache web error log file for details on what broke. It should at least point you in the right direction (such as missing file, missing function, etc)